# Hay una manera de cambiar el color del boton en android studio?

Tags: android-studio

Estuve probando lo siguiente:

```
if(x==1){
  button.setColor(#D32F2F);
  // o de algo a si 
  button.setBackground(#D32F2F);
}
```

No sé si me entienden ya que soy algo nuevo en esto.
Los botones los quiero para que cambien de color según el estado  si es `0`: rojo, si es `1`: verde y si es `3`: gris.

Answer (score 1):

Si puedes cambiarlo, esto debería funcionar:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.push_button);
//un archivo drawable
btn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.my_bg));
//o un color
btn.setBackground(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.my_color));
```

Comment: Hola disculpa que va en donde dice  context ???

Comment: Si estas en una activity es this o Context context = this, si es un fragmento necesitarás traerlo con getActivity()